# Animating CIFilter CIPerspectiveCorrection

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, catransform3d

I'm trying to do an image cropping feature with perspective correction.
I've had success with using CIFilter CIPerspectiveCorrection.

My question is: how do I animate from original image to my cropped image (with the correction)?

`layer.filters` is not supported for iOS as per documentation.
I'm thinking maybe `CATransform3D` is the way to go, but I'm not familiar with transforms and matrices.

I'm looking for the same animation like cropping in CamScanner app.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way, but kinda brute way to go at it. What I did was to create multiple images interpolated from initial image and final image, then added a `CAKeyFrameAnimation`.

```
let points: [CGFloat] = [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0]
    for i in points {
        let TLx = originalQuad.topLeft.x + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.topLeft.x - originalQuad.topLeft.x)
        let TLy = originalQuad.topLeft.y + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.topLeft.y - originalQuad.topLeft.y)
        let TL = CGPoint(x: TLx, y: TLy)

        let TRx = originalQuad.topRight.x + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.topRight.x - originalQuad.topRight.x)
        let TRy = originalQuad.topRight.y + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.topRight.y - originalQuad.topRight.y)
        let TR = CGPoint(x: TRx, y: TRy)

        let BLx = originalQuad.bottomLeft.x + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.bottomLeft.x - originalQuad.bottomLeft.x)
        let BLy = originalQuad.bottomLeft.y + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.bottomLeft.y - originalQuad.bottomLeft.y)
        let BL = CGPoint(x: BLx, y: BLy)

        let BRx = originalQuad.bottomRight.x + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.bottomRight.x - originalQuad.bottomRight.x)
        let BRy = originalQuad.bottomRight.y + i * (cartesianScaledQuad.bottomRight.y - originalQuad.bottomRight.y)
        let BR = CGPoint(x: BRx, y: BRy)

        let filteredImage = ciImage.applyingFilter("CIPerspectiveCorrection", parameters: [
            "inputTopLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: BL),
            "inputTopRight": CIVector(cgPoint: BR),
            "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: TL),
            "inputBottomRight": CIVector(cgPoint: TR)
            ])

        if let image = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(filteredImage, from: filteredImage.extent) {
            images.append(image)
        }
    }

    let anim:CAKeyframeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
    anim.duration = 0.5
    anim.values = images
    anim.delegate = self

    imageView.layer.add(anim, forKey: "contents");
    imageView.layer.contents = images.last!
```

Having issue with incrementing values so I had to hardcode every point. Works fine, and looked good. Although the overhead from creating `CGImage`s is noticeable, especially if more frames are generated.

Hopefully, Apple will support `layer.filters` on iOS in the future.